# Identify this spa

Tags: appliances

I have been left with this spa by previous house owner, can someone identify How many people is this supposed to accommodate (what type of spa this is)? There is no business brand or logo on it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you removed the maintenance panel? I'd sure think that there's some branding somewhere on it.

Comment: I agree with @isherwood, usually there is a marking of some sort inside the pump control area. Just be careful not to confuse the label on the pump or control system for the tub manufacturer. From what I can tell, it looks like what is considered a 2 or 4 person tub.